# Do all computable functions on ordinals satisfy this certain modular property?

Tags: computability, ordinals

Consider the following property of a non decreasing function $f$ whose domain and codomain are each the set of ordinals less than the Church-Kleene ordinal, and whose set of fixed points is unbound.

> There exists a fixed point $\alpha$ of $f$ such that, for $\beta>\alpha$ any fixed point of $f$, and $\beta^\prime$ the first fixed point of $f$ after $\beta$, the following holds for $\gamma$ any ordinal in $[\beta,\beta^\prime)$.
>
> 1) $f$ is computable in $[0,\beta)$.
>
> 2) If $\gamma=\beta+\delta$, then $f(\gamma)=\beta+f(\delta)$.

Is it known if there is any function satisfying the first condition but not the second? If so, can anyone provide an example?

#### EDIT

I have been asked to clarify the following. Let $f$ be computable in an interval $I$ if there is a computable ordering of the naturals isomorphic to the ordering of $I$, and there is a computable function on the naturals which mirrors $f$ relative to this ordering.

Comment: I added the answer to the first question to my question. And yes, we are considering all relevant ordinals computable.

Comment: Are you also assuming that $f$ has unboundedly many fixed points? Since $\omega_1^{CK}$ is countable, this isn't necessarily true . . . (Also your (1) doesn't involve $\gamma$ at all; is that a typo?)

Comment: Yes, when I say $f$ maps the Church-Kleene ordinal to itself, I mean as a set. The range and domain are the Church-Kleene ordinal.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming $f$ has unboundedly many fixed points. And (1) is not based on $\gamma$, $\gamma$ is only relevant to condition (2).

Comment: Do you really mean the *range* of $f$ is $\omega_1^{CK}$, not the codomain? That is, $f$ has to hit every computable ordinal?

Comment: I mean codomain, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider the following function (where "$\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$" denotes the floor function):

- $f(n)=\lfloor{n\over 7}\rfloor$ if $n$ is finite,
- $f(\alpha)=\alpha$ if $\alpha$ is a limit,
- $f(\lambda+n)=\lambda+\lfloor{n\over 10000}\rfloor$ if $\lambda$ is a limit and $n$ is finite.

This $f$ is nondecreasing and onto $\omega_1^{CK}$, has a club of fixed points, and satisfies (1) (by standard mucking about with ordinal notations). However, it does not satisfy (2).

Comment: Can you please explain how it fails to satisfy (2)?

Comment: @Kyle Well, let $\beta$ be any fixed point - that is, limit ordinal - and consider $\gamma=\beta+20$ (say). Then $f(\gamma)=\beta$, but $\beta+f(20)=\beta+1$, so $f(\gamma)\not=f(\beta)+f(\delta)$ ($\delta$ in this case being $20$).

Comment: Thank you, that does answer the question as I asked it. However, I realize now that I misformulated the question. So I will select this answer and ask the question formulated as I intended as a new question.

Comment: I reposted, I don't really know the protocol when a question needs to be totally restated, if there is anything else I should do please let me know.